# Is there a way to use QGIS' qgis:tilesxyzdirectory algorithm from a shell script?

Tags: qgis, kml, png, shell

I currently have a KML file which I upload to QGIS as a layer. From there I navigate the UI to Raster tools -> 'Generate XYZ tiles (Directory)' under the processing toolbox.

For the EXTENT parameter that is required I manually choose the KML layer I just uploaded and it writes it off as `-100.054053000,-94.647180000,33.702234000,37.125712000 [EPSG:4326]`.

I want to automate this process through a shell script and I came across this explaining how to use the qgis_processor to use the algorithms.

https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing/standalone.html

https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rastertools.html#generate-xyz-tiles-directory

My idea is to use something like this in a shell script

`C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.16.9/apps/qgis-ltr/bin/qgis_process.exe run qgis:tilesxyzdirectory -- EXTENT=? ZOOM_MIN=0 ...`

But then how would I go about grabbing the extent from the KML? I imagine the extent is obtained from the QGIS UI from the layer that was created from the KML. Is there a way to do this without the GQIS GUI?

Comment: You could use `ogrinfo filename.kml -so -al | findstr "Extent"` to grab extent from a vector file in the command line. But it may not go straight into `-- EXTENT`. You will need some custom scripts in bash or python to do string formatting as per the requirement.

Comment: This helped me progress, but is there a way to load the layer that would be used for the qgis:tilesxyzdirectory algorithm from the command line? I imagine that if I try doing `qgis_process run qgis:tilesxyzdirectory -- {PARAMETERS}` it wouldn't be able to run because there is no layer to reference, no layer loaded.